# Java Junit Mock fails for MongoDB because of Null pointer

Tags: java, junit

I am doing unit test case for mongoDB read operation. When I try to mock find operation, I am getting a NullPointerException

```
   public class MongoQueriertest {

        HelperUtil testhelper = new HelperUtil();

        DBCollection feedCollection;
        DBCursor curr;

        @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
        public void test_MongoQuerier ()throws Exception {

            MongoQuerier query = new MongoQuerier();
            FindIterable iterable = mock(FindIterable.class);
            curr =  mock(DBCursor.class);
            BasicDBObject obj = mock(BasicDBObject.class);
            when(feedCollection.find(obj)).thenReturn((DBCursor) iterable);
            query.getMaxId("String");   
        }

    }

Method to test
 public String getMaxId(String dataVersion) throws Exception{
    String  maxJobId = "1";

    try {  

    BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    whereQuery.put("instance", dataVersion);

      DBCursor curr = feedCollection.find(whereQuery);  //.sort(new BasicDBObject(mongoDBSetting.maxIdField.replace("$", ""), -1)).limit(1);

      //AggregationOutput cursor = feedCollection.find().sort(""); //.aggregate(Arrays.asList(query));
      while (curr.hasNext()) {
//      String mid = curr.next().get(mongoDBSetting.maxIdField.replace("$", "")).toString();
//      
//      mid = mid.replace("", "");

        maxJobId =  curr.next().get(mongoDBSetting.maxIdField.replace("$", "")).toString(); //Integer.parseInt(mid);
       }

     /* for (DBObject result : curr.results()) {
        maxJobId = Integer.parseInt(result.get(mongoDBSetting.maxIdField.replace("$", "")).toString());
            break;
      }*/ 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      AppLogger.EventLogger.error("Exception occured selecting maxid in mongoDB. Exception -" + ex.getMessage().toString());
      throw new Exception(ex.getMessage().toString());
    }
    return maxJobId;
  }
```

Please let me know where I am missing. I have added method that needs test case.

Comment: You're calling `find(obj)` on `feedCollection` which was never initialized, what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You record a mock behavior on `feedCollection` that is not actually mocked

```
when(feedCollection.find(obj)).thenReturn((DBCursor) iterable);
```

The object is `null`.

So `feedCollection.find(obj)` throws a `nullPointerException`.

Actually you have mocked these two objects :

```
 curr =  mock(DBCursor.class);
 BasicDBObject obj = mock(BasicDBObject.class);
```

Besides mocking an object is the first step to mock a method but to get it working, the mock object should be associated to the object under test.
And it is not the case. You create the `MongoQuerier` object you want to test but you don't set mocks object to it.

```
MongoQuerier query = new MongoQuerier();
```

You should rather create an instance of the object to test with mocked object.

For example in this way to associate to it the mocked object(s).

```
MongoQuerier query = new MongoQuerier(mockObject, mockObject2, ...);
```

Comment: I have added mock for feedCollection I can able to overcome Null pointer Exception but Mock not works in Method am trying write junit ,I have added method where i am writing testcase @davidxxx

Comment: As explained,  the mock object should also be associated to the object under test. Create a mock object it is only the first step.